# Throttling bandwidth usage at home

Tags: router, home-networking

I have a computer on my home network which I wish to throttle.

I believe I will need to replace my current router but I am unsure what feature set I should be looking for when making my purchase.

Infact, are there different ways of throttling traffic ? If so, what information should I consider when making the choice.

I would preferably like this to work 'out of the box', no 'flashing' required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a D-Link DGL-4100 gaming router.  Has **great** QoS/bandwidth filtering.

Answer (score 8):

If you install [Tomato firmware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_(firmware)) (I'd link if I were allowed, but just Google it) on a Linksys router, you'll get QOS and some throttling features. Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for (if not, what specifically do you need?).

Comment: That's what I use. It smooths out web access while downloading torrents nicely.

Comment: been running tomato for 6 months now.  works great.  keeps voip running well while torrenting or downloading iso's.  also, I like that it keeps download/upload stats.

Answer (score 1):

I use mikrotik [RouterOS](http://www.mikrotik.com/pdf/what_is_routeros.pdf) at most of our sites, has simple queues (based on target address/ip/ip range/packet mark) or full queue tree's for setting up your own QoS systems as well.

Probably the best part about this setup is that I can also use burstable queues, that allow a user to burst above their allowed transfer speed for X amount of time.

Eg: I can assign a queue to a user that limits them to 10Mbps/256Kbps and then set a burstable queue rate of 20Mbps/512Kbps over 60 seconds.

This allows regular web-browsing users etc etc to download at 20Mbps with no problem, soon as a user begins downloading thou, their speed is cut back to the 10Mbps limit.

You can get a preinstalled router from them along with a licence for much less than you'd pay for most decent home-grade routers. (See their sister site http://www.routerboard.com)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean traffic shaping?

Smoothwall does it: http://www.smoothwall.net/products/smoothtraffic2008/

(Try the open source one)

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy smoothwall and/or squid proxy on an extra PC.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a wireless router or something wired that will sit in a rack?  If wireless, I recommend DDWRT.  It will run on alot of routers and is very configurable.  You can give bandwidth priority to a certain machine or allot a small amount to other machines.

Comment: What is DDWRT? Jack

Comment: ddwrt is similar to tomato; it's replacement firmware for various wifi / home routers (linksys, buffalo, netgear, etc): http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/index.php

Comment: Tim is right.  DDWRT is a replacement firmware (linux) for many routers.  Flashing it to your router is a bit technical, but the instructions are wonderful.  I use it at home and work on every router that I have.  Do a Google search for it or check out the wiki 

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

DD-WRT is also my recommendation. It's an open-source custom firmware for the Linksys WRT series routers, and can be found at dd-wrt.com

I've used it for many years and have been quite impressed by it.

Comment: Downvote 2 years later with no explanation? Seriously…